# Microsoft Speech API to read a french text

Tags: text-to-speech

I would like to build an application that reads french text. I have already developed the app and it is able to read the text in English. I only need how to pass a parameter to the speech API so that it would speak in French.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this ? http://www.mperfect.net/speechSamples/

Comment: I have already managed to make it work for English. But, I can not make it work for French language

Comment: When you call GetInstalledVoices() on SpeechSynthetisis, what is returned ? Sacré français

Answer (score 0):

You need a French voice.  Unfortunately, there aren't any free French voices available for SAPI 5 (and therefore usable with the .NET framework).

What programming language are you using?